# How to enable Datatables pagination buttons for infinite results?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, datatable

How do you configure a [Datatable](https://datatables.net/) so that the pagination buttons are always enabled, and trigger the `ajax` data load method?

My data's is too large to load all at once, so I'm using the "function" value for the ["ajax"](https://datatables.net/reference/option/ajax) option to call a custom JSON loading method that can be called repeatedly to load the next page of results.

I'd like that function to be triggered by the user clicking the "previous" and "next" buttons. However, by default, it looks like Datatables assumes the "ajax" method loads all data the first time, so if the results fit in the current table without needing pagination, the pagination buttons are disabled.

I've tried using browser's inspector to dynamically enable them via the CSS attribute, but it looks like that's only asthetic and they don't actually trigger the ajax callback.

How do I fix this? Is this even something that's supported by Datatables?

Answer (score 0):

You should put `serverSide` option to `true` to use ajax.

If you want to make pagination and you don't know how many records you have, you should return this in the ajax response `{ ... "recordsTotal": Length of table, "recordsFiltered": int.MaxValue, ...}` and use `info: false` & `pagingType: 'simple'` options to hide the number of records and show just Next and Previous buttons without pages.

```
   dataTable({
        ......
        processing: true,
        serverSide: true,
        pagingType: 'simple',
        info: false,
        lengthMenu: [10, 25, 50, 100, 250, 500, 1000],
        searchDelay: 1000,
        pageLength: 10,
        ajax: {
            url: 'url',
            type: 'get'
        }
```